# MySQL SELECT IF ID in other table

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select

i need to do a query on a database.

Table "servers"

```
+----------+----------+
| ID       | Name     |
+----------+----------+
| 1        | Server1  |
| 2        | Server2  |
| 3        | Server3  |
| 4        | Server4  |
+----------+----------+
```

Table "warranty":

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| linkType | linkID   | Year     |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 1        | 1        | 2015     |
| 2        | 3        | 2016     |
| 2        | 4        | 2016     |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

servers.iD = warranty.linkID

Now i would like to get a list like:

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| Warranty | ServerID | Name     |
+----------+----------+----------+
| no       | 1        | Server1  |
| no       | 2        | Server2  |
| yes      | 3        | Server3  |
| yes      | 4        | Server4  |
+----------+----------+----------|
```

Means i need a list of all Servers in table "server", with an Infofield "Warranty" (YES/NO).

IF the ID of an Server appears in table "warranty", it should print "yes", else: "no", but ONLY if linkType = 2

I know how to use an SELECT IF(server = "Y", "yes", "no") AS "server?"... Query, but i have no idea on how to SELECT IF an ID is present or not in another table.

Comment: Have you formed any query yet?

Comment: are you familiar with MySQL joins?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * , 
     if(exists (select * from warranty t1 where t.ID=t1.linkID and linkType=2), 'yes', "no") 
  FROM servers t1
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to apply Join and then check your condition on it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to use left outer join here. If warranty will be null or 1 then display no else yes.

Answer (score 0):

You must do `ALTER TABLE Servers ADD Warranty type_donnees` and do the

```
update TABLE Servers set warranty = 'yes' where (
select EXISTS(
   select linkid from warranty were servers.id = linkid
));
```

it's the idea , test it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way:

```
SELECT (CASE
            WHEN w.linkID IS NULL THEN 'No'
            ELSE 'Yes'
        END) AS Warranty,
       s.ID as ServerID,
       S.Name AS Name
FROM servers AS S
LEFT JOIN warranty AS W ON s.iD = W.linkID
WHERE W.linkType = 2
```

Comment: You are missing the linkType condition

Comment: It needs to be as part of the LEFT JOIN otherwise you have effectively written an INNER JOIN and you NULL conditions won't work

Answer (score 0):

First I want you to gather some knowledge on [MySQL JOINS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) and [CASE WHEN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-function/) expression.

**Then try to formulate the query yourself.**

***Only take help if you really get stuck.***

**Explanation:**

If you simply make Left join between these two tables (servers(left table) and warranty)
then the query would look like:

**query #1:**

```
SELECT 
servers.ID,
servers.Name,
warranty.linkType,
warranty.linkID,
warranty.`year`
FROM servers
LEFT JOIN warranty
ON warranty.linkID = servers.ID
ORDER BY servers.ID ASC
```

And you would get the following result:

[image]

Then from this result set if you apply some if else (i.e. CASE WHEN) on the linkType 
then the query would look like:

**query #2:**

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN warranty.linkType = 2 THEN "yes" ELSE "no" END AS Warranty,
servers.ID AS ServerID,
servers.Name
FROM servers
LEFT JOIN warranty
ON warranty.linkID = servers.ID
ORDER BY servers.ID ASC
```

And the final result would look like:

[image]

**N:B:** **query #2** is the final query.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` expression and `JOIN`.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN t1.ID IN 
  (SELECT linkID from warranty WHERE linkType = 2) THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS Warranty,
  t1.ID, t1.Name
FROM servers t1 
LEFT JOIN warranty t2
ON t1.ID = t2.linkID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to use a boolean 1/0 for the yes/no field and convert it to text in the application layer.

I'd also put the linkType in the LEFT JOIN condition.

This makes for a simpler query:

```
   SELECT w.linkID IS NOT NULL AS warranty
          s.ID AS ServerID,
          s.Name,
     FROM servers s
LEFT JOIN warranty w
       ON w.linkID = s.ID
      AND w.linkType = 2
 ORDER BY s.ID
```

In the future I'd also be more consistent with your table names.. `servers` is plural and `warranty` is singular. I'd suggest picking a convention, we use singular table names in our company.